# Mvc Modal popup is working with jQuery 1.5.1.js but loading multiple times for single click, not working with latest (1.8.2.js)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, modalpopup

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".openPopup").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            debugger;
            $("<div></div><p>")
            .addClass("dialog")
            .attr("id", $(this)
            .attr("data-dialog-id"))
            .appendTo("body")
            .dialog({
                title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                close: function () { $(this).remove(); },
                modal: true,
                height: 250,
                width: 900,
                left: 0

            })
            .load(this.href);
        });

        $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
        });
    });
</script>
```

My Calling razor syntax is given below :-

```
 @Html.ActionLink("open modal popup", "About", "Home", null, new { @class = "openPopup", data_dialog_id = "popuplDialog", data_dialog_title = "Popup"})
```

Comment: plz give your html code i.e tags having class .close,.openpopup etc...

Comment: Thanks for ur concern, this working fine with jquery-1.5.1 only.click n close is ok if againclick on it it is loading twice, and multiplying from there, pl help me in this issue

Comment: any console errors????

Comment: just insted of this $(".openPopup").live("click", function (e) {  });   write this $(".openPopup").click( function (e) {  });

Comment: Not really worked, now even popup is not firing.one view is rendering.No errors at all

Answer (score 0):

As of `jQuery 1.7`, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers in new jQuery versions. There is a issue in your code, `$("<div></div><p>")` should be `$("<div></div>")`

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".openPopup").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("<div></div>")
        .addClass("dialog")
        .attr("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id"))
        .appendTo("body")
        .dialog({
            title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
            close: function () { $(this).remove(); },
            modal: false,
            height: 250,
            width: 900
        })
        .load(this.href);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4Rhz/8/)

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion, i tried it got popup but once i close and click again it is loading multiple instances. and in jsfiddle if we close and click onpe again nothing is happening why ?. these are the issue i cant figure it. pl guide me.

Comment: It seems `left` is not an `option` for `dialog`. (http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) I have updated the answer.